# Output not showing properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, nmap

While running the Python3 with nmap argument, output only showing as -1

```
try:
    import os, sys, time
except:
    sys.exit("[!] Install 'os, sys, time' modules: pip3 install os -|- check whether 'Nmap' is installed: https://nmap.org/")


class recon_scanner():

    def nMap(self):
        tgtHost = input("Enter the target: ")
        tgtPort = input("Enter the target port: ") 

        options = input("""\n Please choose an option:
           [1] TCP NULL|sN|+|Pn|+|sV|+|sC|+|O|+|version-intensity 9|+|reason|
           [2] TCP FIN|sF|+|Pn|+|sV|+|sC|+|O|+|version-intensity 9|+|reason|
           [3] TCP XMAS|sX|+|Pn|+|sV|+|sC|+|O|+|version-intensity 9|+|reason| \n""")

        print("You have selected option: ",options, '\n')

        if options == '1':
            scanner1 = os.system("nmap -Pn -sN -A -v --version-intensity 9 --reason" + str(tgtHost) + str(tgtPort))
            print(scanner1)

scan_result = recon_scanner()
scan_result.nMap()
```

Answer (score 1):

try using [os.popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) instead of `os.system`, to get the output as a string:

`scanner1 = os.popen("nmap -Pn -sN -A -v --version-intensity 9 --reason" + str(tgtHost) + str(tgtPort)).read()`

then you can print it like any other string

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for the comment. So i can get the output by print(str(scanner1))